# The larger of two supplementary angles exceeds 7 times the smaller by $4^\circ$. Find the measure of the angle.

Tags: geometry

Let $x = \text{large supplementary  angle}$

Let $y=  \text{small supplementary angle}$

$180^\circ - x = 7(180^\circ -y) +4^\circ$

That is the equation that I derived.

Comment: You have the right general idea, but you've made a couple of errors. Given $x$ and $y$ as you've defined them, you know that $y = 180-x$. Then the equation should be $x$ (the larger angle) $= 7y+4 = 7(180-x)+4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without loss of generality assume $y$ is the large one, then $y=7x+4°$ and $y+x=180°$ so $8x+4°=180°\rightarrow 8x=176°\rightarrow x=22°\rightarrow y=158°$